# Why FormView misses ipdb.set_trace() for post request?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have the following code:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^upload_file', FileFieldFormView.as_view(), name='upload_file'),
    url(r'^success', lambda request: HttpResponse('Hello World!'), name='hello_world'),
]
```

upload_file.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from ..forms import FileFieldForm
import ipdb

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    ipdb.set_trace()
    with open(f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

class FileFieldFormView(FormView):
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = 'reports/upload_file.html'  # Replace with your template.
    success_url = '/reports/success'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                print("hello")
                handle_uploaded_file(f)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            print("invalidated")
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

and upload_file.html template:

```
{% extends "core/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <br/>
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    <br/>
    {% block controls %}{% endblock %}
    
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Instead of landing to ipdb.set_trace() in upload_file.py, I get success page. Why does django miss the breakpoint?

Comment: `files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')` isn't the file field named "file" not "file_field"?

Comment: @IainShelvington we want to upload multiple files.

Comment: Right... but the field is named "file" so you need to use that field name? `files = request.FILES.getlist('file')`

Comment: Does the 'hello' get printed? What happens if you move the set_trace call to just after the print?

Comment: Changing to "file" field helped. @IainShelvington, thank you!